# TSQL Group based on 2 conditions in the same Recordset

Tags: t-sql, group-by, multiple-columns

I have a question which has been confusing me to 2 days. Here is the problem.  I have a table which looks something like this:

[image]

What I would like to do is to have to groupings that end up in the same table.  For the example above, I would end up with the following:

[image]

Can something like this be accomplished?  As you can notice, we are grouping by different columns.  This does not have to be done with one query, however, it does have to end up in one table/dataset.

Comment: Explain how the first row in your result is returned.  Specifically why year is 2010 and why earned is 0.  If it's what I think, you're after two separate queries and a union.

Comment: @xQbert, the Sale Year column is 2010, but nothing was earned during that period

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would sum up each set independently, and then join together using a `full outer join`, since it looks like you may have years with sales, but not years with earnings, or vice versa...

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(PeriodEarnedYear, [Sale Year]) AS [Year],
    Earned,
    Sale
FROM
(
    SELECT
        PeriodEarnedYear,
        SUM(PeriodEarned) AS Earned
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY PeriodEarnedYear
) p FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        [Sale Year],
        SUM(Sale) AS Sale
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY [Sale Year]
) s ON p.PeriodEarnedYear = s.[Sale Year]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need this:

```
select PeriodEarnedYear,
    sum(PeriodEarned) Earned,
    Sale
from yourtable
group by PeriodEarnedYear, Sale
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SaleYear year, 
  0 earned, 
  sum(Sale) sale
FROM yourtable
group by saleyear
UNION
Select PeriodEarnedYear,
    sum(PeriodEarned) Earned,
    Sale
from yourtable
group by PeriodEarnedYear
```

But this makes a few assumptions.